# search through all *.py files

Tags: command-line, grep, find, osx, python

I am using Mac OS terminal (similar to Linux) and trying to find best way to search inside all files on a computer that has extension *.py

What is the best way to achieve this?

I wanted to put 1 keyword for search and quickly show the whole path of these python files are that contain requested keyword in them..

Answer (score 13):

Try this,

```
find / -type f -name '*.py' -exec grep -l "keyword" {} \;
```

Explanation:

- `find / -type f -name '*.py'`: Find files below `/` with `py` extension.
- `-exec grep -l keyword {} \;` Within the files found, `grep` for *keyword* and output the filename instead of the match `-l`.

---

I'm not familiar with Mac OS, but if you have `globstar` option in your shell, you can use the following:

```
shopt -s globstar
grep -l keyword /**/*.py
```

Comment: I think mac has `bash` shell (same as Gnu/Linux), but by default not all gnu tools (some are bsd). Your `find` finds files ending `.py` (there is no such thing as file-name-extensions, on Unix).

Comment: You should add -type f before -name otherwise grep will return errors on directories named with a .py extension as I had on my system from some package

Comment: Good suggestion, added.

Answer (score 0):

To look for the string `needle` in a bunch of Python files in a `haystack` directory:

```
$ grep -l 'needle' haystack/*.py
```

To descend into a directory tree, you could either use `grep -R` or switch to iterating via `find` as in the answer from RoVo.